# Read URLs from external file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the following TikTok Downloader which is working fine.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlparse
import requests


class TikTokDownloader:
    HEADERS = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'DNT': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'video',
        'Referer': 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bs;q=0.8,sr;q=0.7,hr;q=0.6',
        'sec-gpc': '1',
        'Range': 'bytes=0-',
    }

    def __init__(self, url: str, web_id: str):
        self.__url = url
        self.__cookies = {
            'tt_webid': web_id,
            'tt_webid_v2': web_id
        }

    def __get_video_url(self) -> str:
        response = requests.get(self.__url, cookies=self.__cookies, headers=TikTokDownloader.HEADERS)
        return response.text.split('"playAddr":"')[1].split('"')[0].replace(r'\u0026', '&')

    def download(self, file_path: str):
        video_url = self.__get_video_url()
        url = urlparse(video_url)

        params = tuple(parse_qsl(url.query))
        request = requests.Request(method='GET',
                                   url='{}://{}{}'.format(url.scheme,
                                                          url.netloc, url.path),
                                   cookies=self.__cookies,
                                   headers=TikTokDownloader.HEADERS,
                                   params=params)
        prepared_request = request.prepare()
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.send(request=prepared_request)
        response.raise_for_status()
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            choice = input('File already exists. Overwrite? (Y/N): ')
            if choice.lower() != 'y':
                return
        with open(os.path.abspath(file_path), 'wb') as output_file:
            output_file.write(response.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--web-id', help='Value of tt_webid or tt_webid_v2 cookie (they are the same).')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='download.mp4', help='Full output path.')
    parser.add_argument('url', help='Video url (https://www.tiktok.com/@username/video/1234567890123456789 or https://vm.tiktok.com/a1b2c3/).')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    downloader = TikTokDownloader(args.url, args.web_id)
    downloader.download(args.output)
```

The issue is that I have to run this command to download each video:

```
python3 ./tiktok.py --web-id 1234567890123 -o ./file.mp4 https://vm.tiktok.com/...
```

And I have 1000 links to download. All the links are in A txt file without comma. Like:

```
Https://tiktok.com/1
Https://tiktok.com/2
Https://tiktok.com/3
```

So- I'm looking to find a way to read the text file and automatically replace the link in the command that I have to run. Or should I change the actual script?

Comment: You want to do it inside python script or write a shell script which will execute your python script?

Comment: Whichever is easier. Have no preference.

Comment: Iterating over text files is simple, just choose a way and proceed. There're thousands of questions there which can help you with that, use a search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use my code please, I have just defined a function that will help you to download all those videos by just entering the path where the file with a thousand links is located, preferably save this python script in the same directory where your file with a thousand links is located:

Use the function

```
A_thousand_links_jbsidis("my_file_with_1000_links.txt")
```

This is going to put automatic names to each video based on date and time, I tested it and it works!

Here is the code by jbsidis:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlparse
import requests


class TikTokDownloaderjbsidis:
    HEADERS = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'DNT': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'video',
        'Referer': 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bs;q=0.8,sr;q=0.7,hr;q=0.6',
        'sec-gpc': '1',
        'Range': 'bytes=0-',
    }

    def __init__(self, url, web_id):
        self.__url = url
        self.__cookies = {
            'tt_webid': web_id,
            'tt_webid_v2': web_id
        }

    def __get_video_url(self) -> str:
        response = requests.get(self.__url, cookies=self.__cookies, headers=TikTokDownloaderjbsidis.HEADERS)
        return response.text.split('"playAddr":"')[1].split('"')[0].replace(r'\u0026', '&')

    def download(self, file_path: str):
        video_url = self.__get_video_url()
        url = urlparse(video_url)

        params = tuple(parse_qsl(url.query))
        request = requests.Request(method='GET',
                                   url='{}://{}{}'.format(url.scheme,
                                                          url.netloc, url.path),
                                   cookies=self.__cookies,
                                   headers=TikTokDownloaderjbsidis.HEADERS,
                                   params=params)
        prepared_request = request.prepare()
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.send(request=prepared_request)
        response.raise_for_status()
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            choice = str('jbsidis File already exists. Overwrite? (Y/N): ')
        print("Downloading jbsidis == "+str(file_path))
        with open(os.path.abspath(file_path), 'wb') as output_file:
            output_file.write(response.content)



import time
import random

def A_thousand_links_jbsidis(file_with_a_thousand_links):
    n=open(file_with_a_thousand_links).read()
    m=n.splitlines() #guessing the links are per line
    MyWebIDis="1234567890123" #put the id that works for you

    c=0
    for new_url in m:
        c=c+1
        new_auto_file_name=str(c)+" - "+str(time.strftime("_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"))+"_video_"+".mp4" #i guess they are mp4
        
        clean_url=str(new_url).replace("\n","").replace("\x0a","").replace("\x0d","").replace(" ","")
        downloader = TikTokDownloaderjbsidis(clean_url, MyWebIDis)
        downloader.download(new_auto_file_name)
        time.sleep(10) #just in case the internet is not that fast, wait 10 seconds after next download
    


A_thousand_links_jbsidis("my_file_with_1000_links.txt")
```

And here is the image, I don't know why sometimes we answer questions without giving a real solution, greetings from El Salvador.

jbsidis
[image]